# Throw Debugeger Warning in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a kind of Compiler-Warning when a certain condition within the argument-list of a method fails. The reason I don´t just throw an exception is, that the user may have the possibility to just put a "bad" argument to the method but then the methods result is kind of unpredictable. Si I just want to give him a hint, that the given parameter may not be valid, such as the usual debug-warning within Visual Studio that state "unreachable Code detected" or "variable never used" or such.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: Just a sample piece of code:

```
void main() {
    MyObject m = new MyObject();
    this.doSomething<MyObject>(m);
}

T doSomething(object m) {
    // put a message to the compiler-warnings that states the used object should derive from type T
}
```

Comment: Do you want to "throw" it into a debugging session or during the program normal operation?

Comment: Not only during Debugging but during normal coding-session also...

Comment: Throw an exception. A programmer calling a method with undefined behavior is just a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: But this will only help me during the execution of my program, not while writing the actual code. I assume the "debugging" inf my tiutle is somehow misleading, I suppose it doesn´t have anything to do with the debugging itself... I think this behaviour is caused by compiler, sorry for this misanderstanding

Comment: Could you write an example of what you want? At writting code/compile time, the actual value of the parameter being passed will not be known (unless it is a literal). The only thing that I know that is ever remotely related might be are the `warning` or `error` directives, but I find it unlikely that they mean what you want  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963th5x3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Add constraints to the method. this will generate compiler errors. like `where T : IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message)
```

where message is the debug message you want to write.

An alternative that may be syntactically convenient for debugging is

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(condition, message)
```

where condition is a Boolean condition, and message is displayed only if the condition evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

The C# compiler does not expose an extensibility mechanism for this sort of thing.  However, this sounds like an very good candidate for a custom FxCop/Visual Studio Code Analysis rule.